# Python 3 metaclass defined functions not visible in the class derived from metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I am working on a python 3 based metaclass, as i understand metaclass a typedef

of a class. Here is a small example

```
class smallClass(type):

    def __init__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        super(smallClass, self).__init__(clsname, bases, clsdict)
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 15
        print(self.addnos())

    def addnos(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def __new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        return super(smallClass, self).__new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict)

class smallClass2(object, metaclass=smallClass):
    la = smallClass.addnos

clstest = smallClass2()

clstest.addnos() ''' this does not work:  AttributeError: 'smallClass2' object has no attribute 'addnos'  '''
```

strange thing is function addnos is not visible from smallClass2 even it is based on metaclass smallClass that included addnos function

can someone help to understand how to access functions defined in metaclass? Or why clstest.addnos() does not work?

Function addnos can be accessed from metaclass but not from derived class, why?

Here another alternative try, have the same problem

```
class smallClass(type):


    def __init__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        super(smallClass, self).__init__(clsname, bases, clsdict)
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 15
        print(self.addnos())

    def addnos(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def __new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        return super(smallClass, self).__new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict)


class smallClass2(object, metaclass=smallClass):
    pass

clstest = smallClass2()
clstest.addnos()
```

Comment: my question is why clstest.addnos() does not work?

Comment: When you assigned `smallClass.addnos` to `la` you explicitly created an additional name for that function in `smallClass2`'s dictionary. Without it, trying to access `clstest.addnos` fails because the metaclass isn't consulted when attribute look-up is performed on an instance.

Comment: Jim, thanks for quick reply print(clstest.la()) works that meas function addnos still belongs to smallClass and it does not propagate to smallClass2. I was not expecting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand what is your intention, and whether you really need a metaclass at all. But here is what is happening:

A metaclass in Python is a class-object class. I think it is easy to visualize that with an example on the (iPython) terminal :

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:    pass
   ...: 
   ...: a = A()
   ...: 

In [2]: type(a)
Out[2]: __main__.A

In [3]: type(A)
Out[3]: type
```

In this case, "A", returned by `type(a)` is the class of the object "a", and "type" returned by "type(A)" is the class of the object "A" - the trick is that in Python even classes are objects: they are all instances of "type" or of a subtype of "type". This role of "class of a class" is what is termed "metaclass".

When ou inherit from "type", instances of the class ou create will be classes themselves. And there is syntactic support of the language, in the form of the "named parameter" on the class statement, to select the metaclass for a class body.

All that said, this is how attribute retrieval works in Python (shortened version - I won't enter into "descriptors" or the setattr, getattr and getattribute mechanisms which add a lot of steps):

When you request an attribute from an object, Python first(*) looks into that object's `__dict__` attribute, which must be  mapping, if it contains the requested attribute. If not, it looks for the attribute on the object's class (on the class `__dict__` as well). If the class of the object does not have the attribute, Python looks for it on the *superclasses* of the object - but it does not step into the class'class to look for the attribute. (It follows the metaclasses as they endup in the class `__mro__` attribute).

So, if I do:

```
class MyMeta(type):
   test = "value from metaclass"
   other_test = "Other metaclass value"

class A:
   test = "value from ancestor class"

class B(A, metaclass=MyMeta):
   pass

b = B()
```

For the instance "b", Python can find "test" as defined in "A", but it will never automatically find the "test" as defined in "MyMeta", nor it will see "other_test". This is what is taking place in your code.

If one needs to see from an instance values as they are defined in the metaclass, all one have to do is to step through the class - so, if a method in B wants to get to "other_test" above, this will work:

```
class B(A, metaclass=MyMeta):
   def method(self):
        print(self.__class__.other_test)
```

(Not that `test`, however would still be shadowed by the `test` defined in the ancestor class in `A`)

All said, I find it very little probable that you actually need a metaclass for whatever you are trying there. It looks more like you want the behavior for simple class inheritance.

(*) Always having in mind this is a super-simplifed description of the attribute lookup algorithm. The first lookup for an attribute is actually in the instance's class itself, looking for a "descriptor" object.

Comment: Thanks jsbueno, your answer is helpful, but i was still not able to execute the function addnos. if I add    def method(self):
        print(self.__class__.addnos)
        self.__class__.addnos() in the smallClass2,  I can see the object of addnos is visible. Is it possible to provide the change that will make the function execute?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is meaninguful in anyway.  If you think you really need a metaclass there, use the metaclass `__init__` function to inject  `addnos` to the new class itself. (That is the "self" parameter you get on the metaclass `__init__` - you already inject "a" and '"b"  into the class): `self.addno = self.__class__.__dict__['adnos']` inside the metaclss' `__init__`.

Comment: jsbueno, when I run above code, getting following error:     B.method()
TypeError: method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. I tried with number of different ways. Again, thank you for help.

Comment: Please, go some steps back, and tell us _what_ are you trying to do. The only possible reason I can think of to want to put ordinary methods nside a metaclass is _exactly_ to _hide_ them from the instance.

Comment: I am working on a python application framework that is used as library. When a class instantiated to create a module I would like to select number of things like which decorators to apply on the functions, what interface API need to be enforced based on top level feature selection, add debug statements to trace the code execution etc. I started watching http://www.dabeaz.com/ excellent introduction. For this specific question I am looking at slide 71 from this presentation. http://www.dabeaz.com/py3meta/Py3Meta.pdf

Comment: The example on slide 71 is maningless (and not even in Python3 - meaning it was not run at all) - but it would result in exactly what you got: the "bla" method exposed in the class, but not in instances of the class